# Creates a trigger send definition in Marketing Cloud Using REST API or SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, marketingcloudapi

I follow the link: "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createSendDefinition.htm" to create trigger send definitaion . I got the same response as mentioned in the document, but when I check under interaction > triggersend, nothing has created. I checked with salesforce support, even they were unsure about this. I believe, we need to give the folderID somewhere in jason code to create the triggersend definitaion but not sure about this. Our use case is to create triggersend definition automatically either using rest api or SSJS. I am very much new to marketing cloud, so i am not that comfortable to use SSJS. I got an SSJS link: "http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/send_server_side_javascript_functions/" as well but its landing to salesforce help document. So not sure how to proceed further.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the request used?

Comment: @zuzannamj, I have used the request: "https://pub.s4.exacttarget.com/0mrkzn35dnn". I got the response as 201 created but when I check under interaction > triggersend, nothing has created. Please let me know if you need any further informations

Comment: @zuzannamj even I just tried this REST method, and even I noticed the same!... Please find my POSTMAN screenshot!...https://pasteboard.co/INaNHkt.png... even if I hit the same request again it gives already exists, but unable to find in tool!!...https://pasteboard.co/INaO8m9.png ....... FYI I was able to achieve the same successfully via SOAP method and also find in tool.

Answer (score 3):

This [REST Route](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createSendDefinition.htm) is only for [transactional messaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-api.htm), which does not have a UI component currently. If you want the API calls for triggeredsends within the UI, you would need to use [SOAP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/triggered_email_scenario_guide_for_developers.htm) to create these